# Selecting repeated values using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

I have this XML,

```
<ROOT xmlns="Exceptions">
    <Header>
        <DateTime>2013-06-03 10:36:01</DateTime>
        <Date>2013-06-03 10:36:01</Date>
    </Header>
    <Exceptions>
        <Exception>
            <Reference>1370252101917</Reference>
            <Fatal>N</Fatal>
        </Exception>
        <Exception>
            <Reference>1370252101918</Reference>
            <Fatal>Y</Fatal>
        </Exception>
    </Exceptions>
</ROOT>
```

I can select the first Reference tag using `ROOT/Exceptions/Exception/Reference`, how can I select the second occurrence of the Reference tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used xpath in java, but ROOT/Exceptions/Exception/Reference should match both elements that have that path, and you should get a list (maybe the function you're using only returns the first match?)

Anyway,

```
ROOT/Exceptions/Exception[2]/Reference
```

matches the reference element in the second exception

Comment: Yeh I think maybe the xPathEngine I am using will just return the first value. This works great though, thanks!